# frequency counter

Tags: frequency, counter, pulse

I am an amateur in electronics and am going to make an RF frequency counter. So after searching, I selected this [circuit](https://bestengineeringprojects.com/frequency-counter-schematic-using-microcontroller-at89c51/) but my input signal is RF while the input of the circuit is a pulse. For receiving RF signal, I have used LM386 and also used the [circuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rqzRw1Yoyk) for converting the sine wave to a square wave.

Unfortunately Microcontroller AT89C51 doesn't count square wave and only accept pulse signal. How do  I convert square to pulse using the AT89c51?

Comment: "Unfortunately Microcontroller AT89C51 doesn't count square wave and only accept pulse signal." You're misunderstanding something here. The timer peripheral of the microcontroller would be configured to count edges (either low→high or high→low transitions) in an application like this. Both "square waves" and "pulses" have rising and falling edges to count.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Can you give me simple circuit for using RF Antenna?

Comment: An AT89C51 is not suitable for measuring RF frequency.  The chip has a maximum clock frequency of 24MHz and its counter only samples the input signal once per 6 cycles, i.e. the fastest this chip can count is 2MHz (due to requiring 2 transitions per input cycle).

Comment: @jules Completely incorrect. The counter Timer 1 will count any direct frequency as an external input ..it has nothing to do with the internal clock. And don't get hung up on RF ...it could mean anything from kHz to Ghz. In this case the AT89C51 is unlikely to count beyond about 20 MHz but that could well be an RF signal from an antenna. The op failed to disclose what frequencies were being used of course.

Comment: @JackCreasey He's right. Take a look at the [C51 hardware manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc4316.pdf), 2.9.1 Timer/Counter operations (page 81): "For counter operation (C/Tx# = 1), the timer register counts the negative transitions on the Tx external input pin. The external input is sampled every **peripheral cycle.**" Turns out the peripheral clock maxes out at 1/6 the main clock. This is a very old microcontroller, which is probably why it has such odd limitations.

Answer (score 5):

The LM386 is an audio amplifier and is completely unsuitable for RF. Your link is to a video so I'm not going to watch it, but I did see LM741 (ugh) so...

You need to convert your RF signal to a 0/5V square-ish wave to input it into the Microchip 89C51. The MCU counts edges and as long as the input is not so short it fails to recognize it, square or pulse makes not difference (square is better).

For that you can use a *comparator*, not an op-amp. It has to be fast enough to handle whatever your "RF" frequency is, and the circuit has to provide a 0/5V signal for the MCU. You may need a buffer amplifier ahead of it.

There are many such comparators available. For example, [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv3502.pdf) but you can pick out something suitable for your particular application.

P.S. you may or may not get specific recommendations here, but one way to guarantee none is to not specify the input frequency range and the input level and impedance. A 100uV 300 ohm 10MHz signal will call for a significantly different circuit from a 3V 600kHz input.

Comment: Yes, I am quite skilled in that regard.

Comment: Unfortunately your proposed comparator (TLV3502 ...) isn't in my country. Can you suggest different models?

Comment: @HFAR you can buy a TLV3502 anywhere; there are vendors who will send them to wherever you are.

Comment: I have a question about LM741. After LM741, Can i use AND or NAND gate instead of buffer? For exp, 74HC00 or 74HC08

Comment: @HFAR: Did you read Spehro's answer? The LM741 is an obsolete and unsuitable op-amp and the LM386 is intended as an audio amplifier. This is not a free design service. You need to study and understand before you can design and build your project.

Comment: I suggest a differential-long-tailed-pair be your comparator. Now you need transistors with Ftau >> RF carrier frequency.

Comment: Thanks my friends. I have a request, please tell me a suitable op amp for RF frequency instead of LM386.